# Msg 244 ..Conversion of varchar value overflowed and Int2 col

Tags: sql-server-2008

When running the following code I get this error:

> Msg 244, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   The conversion of the varchar value '20170719140233' overflowed an INT2 column. Use a larger integer column.

I know the issue is on the last join as I don't get the error without it.

I have checked the datatype for each column in each table on which the last join is based. They are the same (i.e. column `note_nbr` is datatype `varchar` in both tables. Columns `cn.curr_note_vers` and `dn.note_vers` are both `smallint`).

Any help as to what I could look into next appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    g.LDG_NAME,
    g.ACCNBRI,
    g.doc_ref1,
    dn.short_note,
    g.AMT1,
    g.DOC_XREF,
    g.OS_AMT1
FROM 
    GLF_LDG g
LEFT JOIN 
    TRN_NOTE tn ON g.ldg_name = tn.ldg_name
                AND g.accnbri = tn.accnbri
                AND g.trans_nbr = tn.trans_nbr
                AND g.seqnbr = tn.seqnbr
                AND g.vers = tn.vers
LEFT JOIN 
    NOTE_CTL cn ON cn.accnbri = tn.accnbri
                AND cn.ldg_name = tn.ldg_name
                AND cn.note_nbr = tn.note_nbr
                AND cn.curr_note_vers = tn.note_nbr
LEFT JOIN 
    NOTE_DET dn ON cn.ldg_name = dn.ldg_name
                AND cn.accnbri = dn.accnbri
                AND cn.note_nbr = dn.note_nbr
                AND cn.curr_note_vers = dn.note_vers
```

Comment: Can you please tag the database which you are using?

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but your cn join does 'cn.curr_note_vers = tn.note_nbr' not tn.note_vers.